# apache httpd and tomcat: call tomcat features?

Tags: java, php, tomcat, content-management-system, apache

i would need your help on deciding which technologies to use for my next project.

It is basically just a (dynamic) homepage but with login and a file repository.
As WCMS i will probably use Wordpress, Drupal, Joomla!, or Typo3 - not sure yet.

I got a very powerful Enterprise Document Management Application which provides much functionality like a File Repository, User Authentication/UserGroups/Roles/Categories/Tags, ...

Because it is also webbased i would like to use it for the Homepage to manage Logins, and all Files. The only problem: It's written in JAVA (on top of the Spring Framework) and uses a JSP container like tomcat. It has many interfaces to integrate it like REST or CMIS. It's name is Alfresco.

I know there is the possibility to integrate tomcat with apache httpd server but how could i manage the login process?

I would like the httpd server to serve all pages. Login should be handled by tomcat. I want the file repository managed also by tomcat.

For example: Creating new websites with Wordpress using templates and other stuff but not every website is for every user. Some users see more than others. Cusomers should have access to the customer-area where they can download some files.

Currently i have no idea how to do that? Can PHP get and process requests to tomcat (for example a list of downloadable files) or check if a website is accessable by the current user? Or how to get user-information from tomcat?

Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry, maybe I misunderstood your request, but the Alfresco permission/roles/users/group subsystem is not managed by Tomcat. It stores natively all the user information inside the Alfresco itself.
Only if you use some AD/LDAP or kerberos external authentication system, you could manage that. I didn't understand what you would like to use to manage users from Alfresco, you could see here:
[Alfresco Authentication Subsystems](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_Authentication_Subsystems#External)

if you find something useful about.

If I missed the point, could you please explain in other terms your problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Sorry for my bad explanation. I know that Alfresco is managing its own users in its own system. I just ment, that Alfresco is a tomcat webapplication and i would like to use Alfresco's User-System for my own homepage. I could use for example the REST or CMIS interface to login, but how to call that in php? Is it even a good idea??

Comment: well, actually, it's not that good, unless you extend the Alfresco application, and do your own application like an extension of Alfresco itself. I mean, it doesn't make sense use some user database of some app to go towards another one.
Anyway, http://code.google.com/p/alfresco-php-sdk/ you have some php sdk for Alfresco here, that can you help use "A PHP library that allows remote access to the Alfresco repository via the Alfresco PHP API."
here are some examples http://code.google.com/p/alfresco-php-sdk/wiki/AlfrescoPHPAPI